# exact match with Elasticsearch query_string

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm able to perform exact match query by following [Elasticsearch boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "some_field.keyword": "some value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`some_field` is indexed as default string type:

```
"some_field" : {
  "properties" : {
    "value" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, I can only use [Elasticsearch query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). This means, I need equivalent query in Lucene syntax.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same way in `query_string query` with `keyword` variation of the field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "some value",
      "default_field": "some_field.value.keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the mapping the OP provided, it should be `some_field.value.keyword`

Comment: Thanks @Val. I missed to notice the mapping.

Comment: @Gibbs How to combine the `query` and `default_field` in single line?

Comment: Why do you need to combine them? If single line, as they are comma separated, you can add it as the same way separated by comma

Comment: @Gibbs Because I'm using Neptune Full-Text Search, it only allows query in single line - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search-query-execution.html

Comment: Thanks for educating me. By departing them in one liner, will it solve the problem?